# Can´t show snackbar in flutter login

Tags: dart, flutter

Im creating a login form in flutter and I want to use snackbar to show a message when login fails. I read this [documentation](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars) and if i have this code should works

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'));
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

But return this error

> Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.

My *login.dart* all code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttercrud/screens/home_page.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String tag = 'login-page';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final logo = Hero(
      tag: 'hero',
      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        radius: 48.0,
        child: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
      ),
    );

    final email = TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      autofocus: false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Usuario',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
    );

    final password = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      obscureText: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Contraseña',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
    );

    final loginButton = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      child: Material(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        child: MaterialButton(
          minWidth: 200.0,
          height: 42.0,
          onPressed: () {
            final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'));
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
           //Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(HomePage.tag);
          },
          color: Colors.blue[300],
          child: Text('Entrar', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        ),
      ),
    );

    final forgotLabel = FlatButton(
      child: Text(
        '¿Contraseña olvidada?',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
    );

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            logo,
            SizedBox(height: 48.0),
            email,
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            password,
            SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            loginButton,
            forgotLabel
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The *scaffold* return a error but i don´t know how can i fix this without rewrite all code.

So the question is: How can i to show the snackbar when login fails and avoid this error? And why this error appears?

**UPDATED**

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
                 content: Text(
                'Usuario/Contraseña incorrecto',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ));
             Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    seriesList = _createSampleData();
    animate = false;
  }
```

And how can i show snackbar when init page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using the context of the widget that creates the Scaffold (the parent context), not the context of the Scaffold itself. Thus the error.

You can fix the error either by creating a method builder that will receive the correct context:

```
Widget _buildLoginButton(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
        child: Material(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        child: MaterialButton(
            minWidth: 200.0,
            height: 42.0,
            onPressed: () {
                final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'));
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
            },
            color: Colors.blue[300],
            child: Text('Entrar', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        ),
     ),
  );
}
```

And refactor the page to use the builder method you've just created:

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Page'),
    ),
    body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => 
            Column(
                children: [
                    .....
                    _buildLoginButton(context),
                    .....
                ]
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Or just extract the login button to its own Widget, without changing any other of your code, and it will receive the proper context.

```
class LoginButton extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: Material(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            child: MaterialButton(
                minWidth: 200.0,
                height: 42.0,
                onPressed: () {
                    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'));
                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                },
                color: Colors.blue[300],
                child: Text('Entrar', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            ),
         ),
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put example extracting the button on is widget?

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre Basically create new stateless widget, I've updated my answer

Comment: I updated my question. Your answer is correct, i test, but i need to show snackbar on init method.

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre During the init there is no widget tree yet, and the it requires you to have one in order to find the scaffold, you have to first assign a global key to your scaffold when it is rendered and invoke the scaffold with a delay in the init method referencing that global key:
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then(
    (_) => _displaySnackbar
  );
}
void get _displaySnackbar {
  _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    duration: Duration(minutes: 1),
    content: Text('Your snackbar message')
  ));
}

Comment: I try your code but something fails.https://gist.github.com/ElHombreSinNombre/4a9dfcbe98a751e87f705748ae1ca3a5 Can you code example? Return 'method showsnackbar was called on null'

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombreYou should put the _scaffoldKey on a Scaffold, not on a Container. There is no Scaffold widget in your gist at all.